# I want to use queryselectorall after using vue filter through v-html

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6

I'm coding using vuejs.

I have implemented highlighting for certain words when the button is clicked.
(I used the word '2' here)

I used v-html and filter.

I want to print all the highlighted elements.

So I wrote the code like this.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="c">asd</button>
    <div class="pg-post" v-for="(post) in filteredList" :key="post.title">
      <h2 v-html="change(post.title)"></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    change(title) {
      return this.$options.filters.highlight(title, this.search);
    },
    me() {
      console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".highlight"));
    },
    c() {
      this.search = "2";
      this.me();
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      filteredList: [
        { title: "asd" },
        { title: "asd2" },
        { title: "hi" },
        { title: "hi2" },
        { title: "hi3" },
        { title: "hi4" },
        { title: "sjs5jsjsj" },
        { title: "sjsjsjssj" },
        { title: "sjsjsjssj22" },
        { title: "sjsjsjssj2222" },
        { title: "hi5" },
        { title: "hi6" }
      ]
    };
  },
  filters: {
    highlight: function(stringToSearch, searchTerm) {
      if (searchTerm === "") return stringToSearch;
      var iQuery = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
      return stringToSearch
        .toString()
        .replace(iQuery, function(matchedText, a, b) {
          return "<span class='highlight'>" + matchedText + "</span>";
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

I used queryselectorall.

But it didn't output.

This is the output.

```
NodeList {constructor: Object}
<constructor>: "NodeList"
name: "NodeList"
```

I want something like this

```
NodeList(8) [span.highlight, span.highlight, span.highlight, span.highlight, span.highlight, span.highlight, span.highlight, span.highlight]
length: 8
0: span.highlight
1: span.highlight
2: span.highlight
3: span.highlight
4: span.highlight
5: span.highlight
6: span.highlight
7: span.highlight
__proto__: NodeList
```

How can I print what I want?

I'm not good at English so I'm not good at explaining.
I'm so sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

querySelectorAll returns a NodeList, not an array.

You could use the spread operator to convert it to an array and the console.log / loop it.

```
console.log(highlights);

highlights.forEach(highlight => {
    console.log(highlight);
});
```